# Finding Functions authorisation code at deploy time

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I am building an application in Functions (in PS/C#) that connects back into other functions via HTTP. Currently these other functions are looked up in a table and called. This table has been manually created.

```
https://{appname}.azurewebsites.net/api/Orchestrate?code={secret}
```

However when the application is deployed (likely from Github) I would need to have some process that automatically populates that storage table.

How can I find the authorisation secrets at deploy / run time.

Answer (score 0):

It seems my ${generic-Search-engine}foo was broken

According to [Azure Functions HTTP and webhook bindings](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/functions-bindings-http-webhook/)

> You can find API key values in the D:\home\data\Functions\secrets folder in the file system of the function app.
>
> If the secrets folder contains a JSON file with the same name as a function, the key property in that file can also be used to trigger the function